# RTSP live stream via AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

Is it possible to view or capture an rtsp stream using AVFoundation on OS X? I have created an AVURLAsset using the rtsp address, but all attempts to do anything with it result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in com.apple.coremedia.formatreaderloader.makereadyforinspection. Am I using the wrong technique, or is this functionality denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVFoundation only supports HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) or progressive download. Unfortunately, RTSP is not yet supported by iOS SDK.

You have to port an open source solution like live555 to ios environment.

Comment: Has anything changed in the last year?

Comment: I believe so but it's difficult to find hard information.

Comment: I advice you to use libvlc. It's easy to use and you are able to get the full functionality of VLC. I'm using it for RTSP streaming from IP cameras currently.